Can't Get WitMotion Accelerometer (WT9011DCL) to connect to Raspberry Pi Model 4B (Raspian OS)
First and foremost, any help is appreciated,
When I try and pair my bluetooth accelerometer (WT9011DCL) to my RPI4b via bluetooth, I keep getting a message that I connected and then immediately get an error and then it says not connected.
[bluetooth]# pair D1:D2:C4:42:EA:E6
Attempting to pair with D1:D2:C4:42:EA:E6
[CHG] Device: D1:D2:C4:42:EA:E6 Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.error.ConnectionAttemptFailed
[CHG] Device: D1:D2:C4:42:EA:E6 Connected: no

If you need more information to help, I'd be happy to provide.  Thank you

What happens if you do connect D1:D2:C4:42:EA:E6?
